# I don't understand the dual syntax of event delegate

Tags: c#

In answer to my other question [How to send custom event message just after control instantiation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379627/how-to-send-custom-event-message-just-after-control-instantiation) I read this:

```
if (ValueChanged != null)
{
   ValueChanged(sender, e);
}
```

What is ValueChanged in the first case ? Not a function as in the second instruction ? How can the same symbol be used for both ... and function ?

uPDATE after james's answer: if ValueChanged is an Object, How can I call it as if it were a Method? Is it a syntactic sugar or alien syntax with some mysterious mechanism behind like calling ValueChanged.Invoke(sender, e); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ValueChanged is a multi-cast delegate, which is an object. If no one has subscribed to the event, it can be null, hence the check. If you want to avoid the check, you can define an empty delegate and assign it to the event.

```
public event EventHandler ValueChanged = delegate {};
```

You can now just call ValueChanged(sender, e) because ValueChanged can never be null.

Comment: But something I still don't understand, if ValueChanged is an Object, How can I call it as if it were a function ? Is it a syntactic sugar with some mysterious mechanism behind ?

Comment: +1 Never thought of initialising it like that. That will make the code a bit cleaner without the obligatory null checks.

Comment: Yes, ValueChanged is an object. It's an instance of EventHandler, which is derived from MultiCastDelegate. When you call ValueChanged(sender, args), the compiler translates this into ValueChanged.Invoke(sender, args). So yes, it's just syntactic sugar. It's worthwhile creating simple programs and viewing the compiled output in .NET Reflector both as decompiled C# and MSIL. You'll learn a lot about what the C# compiler is doing for you...

Comment: It Can still be null deregister the event handler. Pseudo: for each handler in handlers event-=handler. This solution is just as but not as robust so I'd go for the null check any day

Comment: Yes, you could write code to remove all event handlers, thus removing the empty delegate {}. In general, you shouldn't remove event handlers that you don't subscribe. So this is really a bug. Just as easily, you could write code that nulls out the event handler while another thread is trying to execute it. Thus you have a race condition in your null check. Code defensively, not nonsensically.

Answer (score 2):

Like many things in C# there are language features designed to make things easier. Think of `ValueChanged` as a field and that you check that it is null (internally the delegate will check for subscribers) and the second a shorthand version of

```
ValueChanged.Invoke(sender, e);
```

The actual signature of the event is more than a field of course. It exposes a public add/remove property for subscribers as well as a private field for invoking.

Answer (score 1):

ValueChanged is the same in both cases.

First, you check if it is null, which will be the case if there are no subscribers.

Second, you execute the delegate using method-like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Events are just delegates - a reference to a function elsewhere.  When invoking an event like above, we are calling the delegate.  Since the delegate is just a reference to a function, we need to handle the case where it may not have been set previously (I.E. null)

Answer (score 1):

ValueChanged is a *reference* to one or more functions. If there are no references, then the value will be null. If the value is not null, then all of the referenced functions will called by the `ValueChanged(sender, e);` syntax.